# Combine a falling animation with a going up animation on click

Tags: application-development, qml

I am trying to make a moving sprite fall down from the upper left corner to the left down corner. That function is working properly with the SequentialAnimation component. Apart from that, when you click (or touch) the window, the sprite should go up some pixels and then continue to fall from there. When I try to do so, the only thing I seem to be able to make is to reset the y coordinates making the sprite go all the way up to the screen and then continue where it left before instead of where it was.

Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

import "PelicanFunctions.js" as PelicanFunction

/*!
    \brief Flappy Bird like game
*/

MainView {
    id: root
    // objectName for functional testing purposes (autopilot-qt5)
    objectName: "mainView"

    // Note! applicationName needs to match the "name" field of the click manifest
    applicationName: "com.ubuntu.developer.vitimiti.saltybird"

    /*
     This property enables the application to change orientation
     when the device is rotated. The default is false.
    */
    //automaticOrientation: true

    // Removes the old toolbar and enables new features of the new header.
    useDeprecatedToolbar: false

    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)

    MouseArea {
        id: playArea
        objectName: "playArea"

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Image {
            id: pelicanSprite
            objectName: "pelicanSprite"

            x: units.gu(2)
            y: units.gu(2)
            width: units.gu(6)
            height: units.gu(6)
            source: "Pelican1.png"

            SequentialAnimation on source {
                id: flyAnimation
                objectName: "flyAnimation"

                loops: Animation.Infinite

                PropertyAnimation {
                    to: "Pelican1.png"
                }

                PropertyAnimation {
                    to: "Pelican2.png"
                }
            }

            SequentialAnimation on y {
                id: fallingBird
                objectName: "fallingBird"

                NumberAnimation {
                    from: y
                    to: playArea.height - pelicanSprite.height
                    duration: 5000
                }

                onRunningChanged: {
                    if (running !== true && pelicanSprite.y === playArea.height
                            - pelicanSprite.height)
                    {
                        flyAnimation.stop()
                        pelicanSprite.source = "Pelican_Death.png"
                    }
                }
            }

            SequentialAnimation on y {
                id: upBird
                objectName: "upBird"

                running: false

                NumberAnimation {
                    from: y
                    to: y + units.gu(9)
                    duration: 800
                }
            }
        }

        onClicked: {
            fallingBird.stop()
            upBird.start()
            fallingBird.start()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Close voters: Development on ubuntu is on-topic here. This question is using ubuntu specific libraries so it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it with this code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

Page {
    id: gamePage
    objectName: "gamePage"

    title: i18n.tr("Salty Bird")
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Component.onCompleted: {
        header.visible = false
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: playArea
        objectName: "playArea"

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Image {
            id: pelicanSprite
            objectName: "pelicanSprite"

            x: root.margins
            y: root.margins
            width: units.gu(6)
            height: units.gu(6)
            source: "Pelican1.png"

            SequentialAnimation on source {
                id: flyAnimation
                objectName: "flyAnimation"

                loops: Animation.Infinite

                PropertyAnimation {
                    to: "Pelican1.png"
                }

                PropertyAnimation {
                    to: "Pelican2.png"
                }
            }

            SequentialAnimation on y {
                id: fallingBird
                objectName: "fallingBird"

                NumberAnimation {
                    from: pelicanSprite.y
                    to: playArea.height - pelicanSprite.height
                    duration: (playArea.height - pelicanSprite.y
                               - pelicanSprite.height) / 120 * 1000
                }

                onRunningChanged: {
                    if (running !== true && pelicanSprite.y === playArea.height
                            - pelicanSprite.height)
                    {
                        flyAnimation.stop()
                        pelicanSprite.source = "Pelican_Death.png"
                        playArea.enabled = false
                    }
                }
            }

            SequentialAnimation on y {
                id: upBird
                objectName: "upBird"

                running: false

                NumberAnimation {
                    from: pelicanSprite.y
                    to: pelicanSprite.y - units.gu(9)
                    duration: 200
                }

                onRunningChanged: {
                    if (running !== true)
                        fallingBird.start()
                }
            }
        }

        Image {
            id: menuImage
            objectName: "menuImage"

            x: playArea.width - pauseImage.width - width - root.margins
               - root.spacing
            y: root.margins
            width: units.gu(3)
            height: units.gu(3)

            source: "menu.svg"
        }

        Image {
            id: pauseImage
            objectName: "pauseImage"

            x: playArea.width - width - root.margins
            y: root.margins
            width: units.gu(3)
            height: units.gu(3)

            source: "pause.svg"

            MouseArea {
                id: pauseArea
                objectName: "pauseArea"

                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height

                onClicked: {
                    fallingBird.running === true ? fallingBird.stop() :
                                                   fallingBird.start()

                    flyAnimation.running === true ? flyAnimation.stop() :
                                                    flyAnimation.start()

                    flyAnimation.running === true ? playArea.enabled = true :
                                                    playArea.enabled = false

                    flyAnimation.running === true ?
                                pauseImage.source = "pause.svg" :
                                pauseImage.source = "start.svg"
                }
            }
        }

        onClicked: {
            if (pelicanSprite.y > (pelicanSprite.height + root.margins +
                                   root.spacing + pauseImage.height))
            {
                fallingBird.stop()
                upBird.start()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's also now a working pause button and a non working menu button. The problem was solved combining the onClicked function of the playArea and the onRunningChanged one of the upBird animation. Apart from that, the duration should be set depending on what's left to run for the pelican so that the speed is constant, no matter where you click. Otherwise, the closer to the end you clicked, the slower it'd go, trying to run in 5 seconds a smaller distance.

The y option was changed to the pelicanSprite.y instead of simply y, too, making it work properly.